# How can I change location of label when using maximized window

Tags: c#

I have the label1 (show 1 value) that has properties

```
    this.label1.AutoSize = true;
    this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(554, 636);
    this.label1.Name = "label1";
    this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(140, 155);
    this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

It is added in the main form as bellow code

```
this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
//this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

It worked well. However, if I add one more code as

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

I want to auto change location of label 1 such as it still located in the yellow region. Is it possible in C#?

[image]

Comment: You have to use anchoring of that control.Look for `Anchor` in properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual studio labels are by default Anchored to Top and Left. this causes the problem when you maximize your form.

try this line of code

```
this.label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
```

Another way to do this (From Designer)

Click on your label and then Press `F4`, properties window will appear.
See `Anchor` Property.
You can change it to `NONE`. it would solve your problem.